# "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type" exception after api-platform minor version update

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I've stumbled upon a problem while updating my dependencies and I wonder if anyone has any clue about what is going on...

I've narrowed down the cause to something related with `api-platform` and `symfony/routing` dependencies.

The versions were:

```
api-platform/core                       v2.3.0
symfony/routing                         v4.1.3
```

and after the update:

```
api-platform/core                       v2.4.6
symfony/routing                         v4.1.12
```

The error is:

```
{
    "@context": "/api/v1/contexts/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\LeadRequest\"",
    "trace": [
        {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "",
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php",
            "line": 133,
            "args": []
        }
    [...]
```

The entity looks like:

```
/**
 * Class LeadRequest
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"post"},
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LeadRequestRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="lead_request")
 */
class LeadRequest
```

Of course, I've done my googling diligence and I found several posts about the same error, but I've tried their solutions and are not working. To take some out of the way:

Routing order looks just fine:

```
------------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------------------------------- 
Name                                        Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                          
------------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------------------------------- 
api_entrypoint                              ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/v1/{index}.{_format}                     
api_doc                                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/v1/docs.{_format}                        
api_jsonld_context                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/v1/contexts/{shortName}.{_format}        
api_lead_requests_post_collection           POST     ANY      ANY    /api/v1/lead_requests.{_format}               
api_lead_requests_get_item                  GET      ANY      ANY    /api/v1/lead_requests/{id}.{_format}
```

The entity id getter is accessible:

```
    /**
     * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    [...]

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging and research it seems that the problem was caused by a wrong `persist()` method on the entity `DataPersisterInterface` implementation.

Basically, the id had null value, so the exception was thrown:

```
Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\LeadRequest\
```

**This was happening because the entity was never being saved, so the id was never generated.**

Adding the following code to the method implementation solved the problem:

```
class LeadRequest implements DataPersisterInterface
{
    [...]

    public function persist($data)
    {
        [...]

        $this->em->persist($data);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $data;
    }

    [...]
}
```

I still don't know why the tests were green on previous versions of the library.

I will edit this answer if I find further information about the subject.

Comment: Amazing! that was the issue either for me `Api-Platform: 2.5` / `Symfony:4.4` and after some testing the `$this->em->persist($data);` only was enough!

Answer (score 0):

That kind of identifiers are not allowed by default, only "incremental ids".

But you could add your own Identifier normalizer (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/#custom-identifier-normalizer)

Or even more, your custom Data Provider.